# How much of Tales From Silver Lands was taken from actual Mesoamerican folktales?

Tags: tales-from-silver-lands

Charles Finger's 1924 book *[Tales from Silver Lands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_Silver_Lands)* won the [1925 Newbery Medal](http://www.ala.org/alsc/awardsgrants/bookmedia/newberymedal/newberyhonors/newberymedal#20s) (for the "[most distinguished contribution to American literature for children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newbery_Medal)" that year).  Some of the awardees from the Medal's earliest days, such as the first winner, *[The Story of Mankind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Mankind)*, are basically forgotten, while others (e.g. *[Smoky the Cow Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoky_the_Cowhorse)*, *[The Cat Who Went to Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_Who_Went_to_Heaven)*) are still standards of American literature for children.  (Approximately how well remembered these various books are can perhaps be inferred from the lengths of their Wikipedia articles.)

*[Tales From Silver Lands](https://www.fadedpage.com/showbook.php?pid=20190148)* is in an intermediate position.  It is, while still read, somewhat obscure.  There is not a great deal of information available about it online.  Having read the book as a kid, there was an aspect of it that I found puzzling, and when I was recently prompted to look for more information online, I could not find out what I wanted to know.

My confusion was about the way the stories in the book are framed, and where exactly they originated.  *Tales From Silver Lands* is ostensibly a collection of nineteen fantastical tales from Central and South America.  The very first story in the book, "The Tale of Three Tales," includes a frame narrative about how Finger came to hear the story, in Honduras in "a town called Pueblo de Chamelecón which is not much of a town after all."  Finger says that the tale he sets down is true to what he heard:

> [W]hen it came to the old grandmother again she replaced it and told us the Tale of Three Tails, just as I have written it here.

About a third of the book's folktales have introductions like this, written from Finger's point of view.  However, the majority do not, and the versions of the stories that he tells are sometimes very, very different from the "usual" way those stories go.  In particular, the tales of "The Hero Twins," "The Four Hundred," and "The Killing of Cabrakan" (none of which have framing introductions) are very different from the versions of these myths that are recorded elsewhere online.

These stories are part of the major Mesoamerican myth cycle concerning the Hero Twins (Hun Hunahpu and Vucub Hunahpu), telling how they slew the evil [Vucub Caquix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vucub_Caquix) and his giant offspring, [Zipacna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipacna) and Cabrakan.  These stories are part of Book III of the *Popul Vuh*, but the "canonical" versions of the stories are totally different from Finger's.  In the *Popul Vuh*, Vucub Caquix is a bird, who gets shot with a blowgun dar, whereas in *Tales From Silver Lands*, he is a giant like his sons, and the Hero Twins kill him by pulling out his teeth and leaving him to starve.  In the next story, Finger has the titular Four Hundred Boys are led by the Hero Twins to kill Zipacna—whereas in the *Popul Vuh*, the giant gets the best of the Four Hundred and kills them.  There are definite similarities in the way Zipacna finally gets killed in the stories—both versions involving luring him into a trap with a delicious-looking fake crab made of sand—but there are also major remaining differences.

In light of this, what I am wondering was what was the real origin of the tales Finger wrote down in *Tales From Silver Lands*?  Were these alternative versions of myths and folktales that he actually heard in his travels around Latin America, recorded and translated more of less faithfully?  Were they, alternatively, merely inspired by what Finger heard, to which he added a substantial amount of new material?  It might be a combination of these two scenarios, with some of the stories true to what Finger heard and others heavily rewritten and embroidered.  Or is there another explanation entirely.